# What is the difference between map of Python and fmap of Haskell?

Tags: python, haskell

I know that they are both different languages, but then aren't they both essentially the same? fmap applies a function over a Functor, whereas map of Python applies a function over an iterable. So if there is any difference between the two, can you provide an example of something we can do with map of Python but not fmap of Haskell (or vice versa)?

Comment: `map` returns a generator, whereas `fmap` returns lazily the **same datastructure**.

Comment: Specifically, imagine a binary tree of integers, `t`. In haskell, you can write `fmap show t` and receive a binary tree of strings as a result, having the same structure as the input tree. Python's `map` does not understand how to descend into a tree structure.

Answer (score 13):

They’re pretty different.

The two functions do very similar things on list-like things, but that’s really where the similarities end. It would probably be more useful to compare Haskell’s `map` with Python’s `map`, but `fmap` is both far more general and rather different in meaning.

---

In Haskell, `fmap` is a sort of “lifting” or “piercing” operation. It takes a function from `a -> b` and “lifts” it to a function from `f a -> f b`. A list-like container is a sort of thing that can be “pierced”, but so many more things than lists are functors!

Mapping over a `Maybe a` is extremely useful and common, though one might argue that `Maybe` is just like a list of zero or one elements. However, consider the fact that *functions* are functors in Haskell. You can `fmap` over a function and receive a new function, but functions are obviously not iterables. Similarly, parsers in parser combinator libraries like parsec are functors, and you can produce new parsers by `fmap`ping over them to apply a function to their result.

All sorts of things are functors, many of which have little to do with containers that hold values. All monads are functors, including things like `Writer`, `State`, and `Cont`, which are effectful computations, not list-like things. Other things are functors, too, like `Const`, which can be combined with `Lift` to form an applicative functor that monoidally collects errors.

The specifics of what each of these things are and do is outside the scope of this question, but the point is that the Haskell notion of a functor is far more general than an “iterable thing”, and it’s generally used in a different way from Python’s `map`.

---

From another perspective, however, it’s fair to say that Python’s `map` is more powerful than Haskell’s `fmap`. There is a cost to generality, and that’s a need to be simple. Being specific gives you the option to do more things! This, plus Python’s other differences from Haskell (like dynamic typing and variadic functions), makes it possible for Python’s `map` to do things that Haskell’s `fmap` cannot.

As [Daniel Sanchez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1695172/daniel-sanchez) points out, Python’s `map` is variadic, so it acts like `zipWith` in Haskell when provided multiple iterables:

```
>>> map(lambda x,y: x+y, range(10), range(10))
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18]
```

There’s a bit more, though. Python’s `map` can also operate over different sorts of things. In Haskell, the generality of the `Functor` class is useful mostly because it makes it possible to write functions that operate on any `Functor`, and that means all `Functor`s need to act in more or less the same way. The element(s) “inside” a `f a`, if you want to use the container analogy, *must* be of type `a`.

Consider what this means for something like a hash map or dictionary. In Haskell, `Functor`s must have kind `* -> *`, so `Map` can only be a `Functor` if partially applied. Therefore, `Map k` has a `Functor` instance, so `fmap` only operates over the *values* of a `Map`.

In Python, this is not nearly so rigidly enforced by the consequences of the type system, so dictionaries actually function as sequences of their *keys* when iterated over:

```
>>> map(None, {'foo': 1, 'bar': 2})
['foo', 'bar']
```

Oh, and that example also demonstrates another Python oddity—mapping `None` over something acts like mapping the identity function, but mapping it over multiple things acts like Haskell’s `zip` and produces tuples:

```
>>> map(None, [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
```

Finally, note that Haskell’s `fmap` cannot map over sets! Why is this? Well, the rigid type system requires that `fmap` work for *any* values, but `Set`s must be composed of values of a type with an `Ord` instance. Python does not need to jump through any such hoops, so it can map over sets just fine:

```
>>> map(None, {1, 2, 3})
[1, 2, 3]
```

---

Python and Haskell are very different languages. A lot of these differences are simply artifacts of the language differences, not necessarily differences in what the functions are designed to do.

Still, the core difference is simple to summarize: Python’s `map` is for mapping over list-like things, but Haskell’s `fmap` is for lifting a function to operate on an arbitrary data structure. Those two things are quite distinct even once you look past language differences, so don’t assume they’re the same just because that have the same sort of shape on the surface.

Comment: `Set` cannot have a `Functor` instance but it can have a [`RFunctor`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/rmonad-0.8/docs/Control-RMonad.html#t:RFunctor) instance.

Comment: Excellent answer! The only thing I might change is that Python's map isn't only for mapping over list-like things, in that you *could* make things with non-list structure iterable (like trees, or even the dict example you give). But mapping over such a container loses any extra structure and returns only a linear sequence of mapped items.

Comment: "_From another perspective, however, it’s fair to say that Python’s `map` is more powerful than Haskell’s `fmap`_". I'm having a hard time finding this perspective.

Answer (score 3):

Python `map` has one behaviour that Haskell does not:

```
map(lambda x,y: x+y, range(10), range(10))
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18]
```

What it does its iterate over the pairs of n iterables unpacking the values from them and passing them as arguments to the function.
Actually Haskell `map` can't do that due to its type signature 
`fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`

That python `map` usage is similar to Haskell `zipWith`:

```
Prelude> zipWith (\x y -> x+y) [1..10] [1..10]
[2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20]
```

Answer (score 1):

Haskell has *both*; `fmap` is a generalization of `map` that can work with any `Functor`, not just lists.

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
map f [] = []
map f (x:xs) = f x : map f xs
```

Looking at `fmap`, you can see the similarity immediately; we just replace list with an arbitrary functor `f`.

```
class Functor f where
    fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

The instance for lists is trivial, as you might expect; we just use the `map` function we've already defined.

```
instance Functor [] where
    fmap = map
```

But `fmap` can be defined similarly for types similar to, but different than, lists.

```
instance Functor Maybe where
    -- Here, f is a variable representing the function to map, not the
    -- Functor type
    fmap f Nothing = Nothing   -- Nothing instead of an empty list
    fmap f (Just x) = Just (f x)  -- Just x is like a singleton list
```

Even for more complicated types, like trees, `fmap` still effectively just applies a function to each element of the container, preserving the structure of the container just as it did for lists and `Maybe`. The empty tree is exactly like an empty list or `Nothing`; other trees are like lists, except instead of recursively mapping over the tail of the list, you recursively map over *both* subtrees.

```
data BinaryTree a = Empty | Node a (BinaryTree a) (BinaryTree a)

instance Functor BinaryTree where
    fmap f Empty = Empty
    fmap f (Node a l r) = Node (f a) (fmap f l) (fmap f r)
```